# Bates Model on Quantlib

Tags: option-pricing, implied-volatility, quantlib, heston, bates

I am actively trying to price an option using bates model on Quantlib.However,when I input my volatility I find the same Black Prices with the basic Heston Model.I wanted to know if my code was right.

```
import QuantLib as ql
import numpy as np 
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import *

def setup_helpers(engine, expiration_dates, strikes, 
                  data, ref_date, spot, yield_ts, 
                  dividend_ts):
    heston_helpers = []
    grid_data = []
    for i, date in enumerate(expiration_dates):
        for j, s in enumerate(strikes):
            t = (date - ref_date )
            p = ql.Period(t, ql.Days)
            vols = data[i][j]
            helper = ql.HestonModelHelper(
                p, calendar, spot, s, 
                ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(vols)),
                yield_ts, dividend_ts,ql.BlackCalibrationHelper.ImpliedVolError)
            helper.setPricingEngine(engine)
            heston_helpers.append(helper)
            grid_data.append((date, s))
    return heston_helpers, grid_data

def cost_function_generator1(model, helpers,norm=False):
    def cost_function(params):
        pen = 1
        params_ = ql.Array(list(params))
        model.setParams(params_)
        pen_c = 2 * params[0] * params[1] -params[2]**2
        if pen_c < 0:
            pen = 1e50
        #err =np.sum(spreads*(np.array([(opt.modelValue() - opt.marketValue())**2  for i, opt in enumerate(helpers)])))/np.sum(spreads)#[h.calibrationError() for h in helpers]r h in helpers]
        err =  pen * np.sum(spreads * np.abs([h.calibrationError() for h in helpers])**2)/len(helpers)
        if norm:
            return pen *err #pen * np.sum(spreads *np.abs([h.calibrationError() for h in heston_helpers4])**2/np.array(data).reshape(1,195)[0])/np.sum(spreads)
        else:
            return error
    return cost_function


def cost_function_generator2(model, helpers,norm=False):
    def cost_function(params):
        params_ = ql.Array(list(params))
        model.setParams(params_)
        #err = np.sum(spreads*(np.array([(opt.modelValue() - opt.marketValue())**2  for i, opt in enumerate(helpers)])))/np.sum(spreads)#[h.calibrationError() for h in helpers]
        err = np.sum(spreads * np.abs([h.calibrationError() for h in helpers]))**2/len(helpers)
        if norm:
            return err#len(heston_helpers4)
        else:
            return error
    return cost_function

def calibration_report(helpers, grid_data, detailed=False):
    IVMSE = np.sum(spreads* np.abs([h.calibrationError() for h in helpers])**2)/len(helpers)
    if detailed: print("-"*100)
    summary = "IVMSE  : %1.9f" % (IVMSE)
    print(summary)
    return IVMSE
    
def setup_model(_yield_ts, _dividend_ts, _spot, 
                init_condition=(0.02,0.2,0.5,0.1,0.01,0.1,0.1,0.1)):
    theta, kappa, sigma, rho, v0,lambs,mu,sig_v = init_condition
    process = ql.BatesProcess (_yield_ts, _dividend_ts, 
                           ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(_spot)), 
                           v0, kappa, theta, sigma, rho,lambs,mu,sig_v)
    model = ql.BatesModel(process)
    engine = ql.BatesEngine(model) 
    return model, engine

def Constraint(x):
    theta, kappa, sigma, rho, v0,lambda_,mu,sig_v = x
    A = 2*kappa*theta - sigma**2 
    return A

const = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': Cst}
summary= []
```

This is the initial Setup.

This is the initialising step

```
model4, engine4 = setup_model(yield_ts, dividend_ts, spot)
heston_helpers4, grid_data4 = setup_helpers(engine4, expiration_dates, strikes, data,calculation_date, spot, yield_ts, dividend_ts)
initial_condition = (0.02, 0.2, 0.5, 0.1, 0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01)
bounds = [(1e-5,10),(1e-5,100), (1e-5,10), (-.99,.99), (1e-5,10),(0,1),(-1,1),(0,1)]
bnds = ((1e-5,10),(1e-5,100), (1e-5,10), (-.99,.99), (1e-5,10),(0,1),(-1,1),(0,1))
```

And lastly,this is the calibration(it takes 3 mins with 210 data points) :

```
%%time
cost_function = cost_function_generator1(
    model4, heston_helpers4, norm=True)
cost_function2 = cost_function_generator2(
    model4, heston_helpers4, norm=True)
sol = differential_evolution(cost_function, bounds=bounds,maxiter = 50 , tol = 1e-9,popsize=25)
params_ = ql.Array(list(sol.x))
model4.setParams(params_)
sol = minimize(cost_function2,sol.x, bounds=bnds,tol =1e-9,constraints = const)
params_ = ql.Array(list(sol.x))
model4.setParams(params_)
theta_b, kappa_b, sigma_b, rho_b, v0_b , lambda_ ,mu,sigma_v = model4.params()
error = calibration_report(heston_helpers4, grid_data4)
summary.append(["Scipy DE1", error] + list(model4.params()))
```

Moreover,Should I use the `ql.HestonModelHelper` in my case ?

Thank you